# efficiently reading N lines at a time from an input file in perl

Tags: perl

The structure of my input data file is such that it is more logical to read the data in blocks of `N` lines rather than a single line at a time. Of course, I could use something straightforward like

```
my @lines=();
while(!eof($FH)) {
  for(my $i=0;$i<$N;$i++)
   $lines[$i]=<FH>;
   chomp();
  }
  # proceed with analysis of N-size block ##
}
```

Because the input files are very large (GB), however, I wonder whether there is a more efficient solution than a `for` loop. For instance, I found another solution [online](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1007560) that uses the `map` function, although when I try to implement it in my script, it results in an error (`"my" variable @lines masks earlier declaration in same statement`):

```
while(( my @lines = map $_ = <>, 1 .. 4 )[0]) {
  print @lines;
  print "\n";
}
```

Admittedly, I don't understand the significance of the `[0]` in the while block of this code, and another solution suggested using `[-1]` instead.

Given the I/O intensiveness of the operation, I wonder about what would be the most computationally efficient solution to this problem (within the bounds of the Perl programming language).

Answer (score 5):

For simplicity, I would probably advise reading from the main while loop and adding to a buffer:

```
my @buffer;

while (<$FH>) {
    push @buffer, $_;

    if (@buffer == $N || eof) {
        print @buffer;
        @buffer = ();
    }
}
```

Algorithmically, I don't expect any particular method to be significantly faster than any other.  You could try playing around with other methods of reading from the filehandle, but ultimately, I would not expect to find any major speed improvements.

Comment: I think I prefer mine :)

Comment: I like yours too because I have an affinity for avoiding state variables outside of a loop.  It just "feels" tidier to not have to include a variable name 5 times in 10 lines of code :).  However, for new programmers, state variables are probably the first tool they should learn, as their usage is typically easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Once of the things I caught onto very early is that the data *itself* can be used as a state flag. For instance, `if (@buffer) { .. }` works fine if you need to treat the first entry differently. Much better than a `$started` flag

Answer (score 3):

By far the slowest bottleneck in any file IO is disk itself. Perl reads the file in arbitrarily large chunks and searches through them for newlines so that it can hand the data to you one  line at a time. That means that any scheme to read multiple lines at a time will take only a tiny fraction of the time for the next chunk to be read from disk. So, as usual, the most prevalent criterion is how readable the code is.

Once I started coding I could see why the most obvious solution would be a `map`. Unfortunately it would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

use constant N => 4;

while (my @block = grep defined, map { scalar <DATA> } 1 .. N) {
  dd \@block;
}

__DATA__
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

**output**

```
["1\n", "2\n", "3\n", "4\n"]
["5\n", "6\n", "7\n", "8\n"]
["9\n"]
```

But it can be written more cleanly. So far I like this the best

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

use constant N => 4;

until (eof DATA) {
  my ($rec, @block);
  push @block, $rec while @block < N and $rec = <DATA>;
  dd \@block;
}

__DATA__
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

which has identical output.

I'm thinking about something like

```
while (do { ... }) {
   dd \@block;
}
```

but I'm not there yet!

Comment: Switching from DATA to ARGV/STDIN becomes a problem: You require getting EOF twice in a row to end the loop, but that's not always the case.

Comment: First snippet: `a<enter>b<enter>c<enter>^De<enter>f<enter>g<enter>h<enter>^D^D^D^D`; Second snippet is a little better: `a<enter>b<enter>c<enter>^De<enter>f<enter>g<enter>h<enter>^D`. In both cases, the output is `["a\n", "b\n", "c\n"]["d\n", "e\n", "f\n", "g\n"]` instead of `["a\n", "b\n", "c\n"]`.

Comment: @ikegami: But `eof DATA` doesn't consume a record. This requires both a `readline` and a subsequent `eof` to return *false*, and that is fine

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the perl reads data from disk in large amounts and then parcels the reads as needed. I didn't appreciate this point and thought that I/O went back to the disk for each line.

Comment: `eof FH` consumes an EOF notification. While that's not a problem for `DATA`, that can be a problem for other handles (as I've demonstrated).

Comment: @user001, More details: It reads 8KB at once, or 4KB in older versions of Perl. If you have humongous lines, it will actually access the disk multiple times to read a line, but in most cases, it will only need to access the disk (or even the OS) every few lines.

Comment: @ikegami: Thanks for adding that information. Is there logic behind the choice of 8 kb (or 4 kb) rather than another value?

Comment: The discussion happened on the "Perl5 Porters" mailing list. It has web accessible archived that can be googled.